# Parsing comma-separated string using XPATH

Tags: xml, csv, xpath

I have a particular scenario where I want to parse a string like this using XPATH 1.0:

> RESP:0:MSISDN,46455381234:GPRS,PDPCONTEXT,APNID,1,PDPADD,136.225.1.1,EQOSID,1,PDPCONTEXT,APNID,2,PDPADD,136.225.1.2,EQOSID,2,VPAA,0:BAOC,1:BOIEXH,1,1,46455381234,TS10,1,TS20;

The string contains sections separated by semicolons (`;`) which are either simple key value parameters (e.g. `MSISDN,46455381234`) or complex ones separated by comma (e.g. `GPRS,PDPCONTEXT,APNID,1,...`), the parameters are totally dynamic and with no particular order.

The desired output will be:

```
MSISDN,0
GPRS
- PDPCONTEXT
-- APNID,1
-- PDPADD,136.225.1.1
-- EQOSID,1
- PDPCONTEXT
-- APNID,2
-- PDPADD,136.225.1.2
-- EQOSID,2
BOIEXH
- TS10,1,46455381234
- TS20,1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of XPath or XQuery can you use, 3.0 has http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-analyze-string for instance which might help. With XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 you can use `tokenize` and `matches`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use XPATH 1.0 .

Comment: XPath 1? Why did you add a "xquery" tag then? XQuery 1 is an almost super-set of XPath 2.

Comment: In XPath 1, you can substring-before or substring-after to split a string in parts, but that is horribe

Comment: So, do you have XQuery or not? No chance doing this in XPath 1.0.

Comment: Edited. I tried a combination of substring-before and substring-after but it won't work as the strings are separated by the same separator and repeated in dynamic way.

Comment: @JensErat No I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem cannot be solved in XPath 1.0, which only has very limited string manipulation capabilities and lacks support of performing loops or even recursion.

If you can change your XPath implementation to a better/newer one, some thoughts:

- Using XQuery (no matter which version) this is very well possible.
- It might be possible for this rather restricted set of nesting using some regular expressions in XPath 2.0, but you will probably have a hard time building that.
- Use any other programming language you're using to call XPath and construct the tree there.